# Find subset of individuals who have more than 3 observations over 6 months

Tags: r, time

I have a dataframe where each row is an observation of an event. There are two columns, `id` and `date`. I want to make a third column that identifies those individuals (based on `id`) who have 3 or more events over any 6 month period (based on `date`). However, an event can only count as unique if it further than 7 days away from a previous event. Having a third column is not necessary if users can think of another way of accomplishing this.

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)
date <- as.Date(c("2015-01-01", "2015-03-02", "2015-03-05", "2015-01-13", "2015-01-29", "2015-12-15", "2015-01-03", "2015-03-03", "2015-04-03", "2015-01-29", "2015-03-04"),format = "%Y-%m-%d")
df <- data.frame(id, date)
```

In the dummy code above the method should identify individual `id == 3` as having the needed number og observations over the correct interval of time while excluding `id == 1` because observations at date `"2015-03-02"` and `"2015-03-05"` are within 7 days of each other and `id == 2` and `id == 4` because they have <3 observations over 6 months.

Comment: @akrun In my data.frame there are individuals who are followed for several years and may have upto 15 unique observations. I am attempting to find all those that have 3 unique observations over any possible 6 month period, although not counting observations that are within 7 days of a previous observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this helps

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, ind :=  if(all(diff(date) > 7) & all(diff(date) < 60) & .N >2) TRUE 
                         else FALSE , id][]
#    id       date   ind
# 1:  1 2015-01-01 FALSE
# 2:  1 2015-03-02 FALSE
# 3:  1 2015-03-05 FALSE
# 4:  2 2015-01-13 FALSE
# 5:  2 2015-01-29 FALSE
# 6:  2 2015-12-15 FALSE
# 7:  3 2015-01-03  TRUE
# 8:  3 2015-03-03  TRUE
# 9:  3 2015-04-03  TRUE
#10:  4 2015-01-29 FALSE
#11:  4 2015-03-04 FALSE
```

Comment: It looks like this works. Can you tell me why you choose all(diff(date) < 60? Just to be sure I understand, this argument is meant to find those observations that are within 6 months of each other? So wouldn't the correct number be < (365/2)?

Comment: seems to work. I've noted in my logbooks to always check the data.table package functionality before I ask a question, seems like data.table always provided the answer

Comment: @user6571411  It is to check whether the difference between adjacent date are all less than 60 (as I understand the question)